# What kind of electronic part is this on the circuit board?

Tags: analog, components

I've a guitar amp with a little problem, spinning the volume controll, the amp starts craking.

All information I've got are:

- Item list on the internet: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/522355/Ibanez-Tb25.html
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

My questions:

- What means 09HBF25?
- What kind of part is this? I don't think that it is a resistor, maybe a capacitor?
- What could be a alternativ item to change them?

Answer (score 2):

You have two potentiometers marked "B 104" and "A 104": -

[image]

I would estimate that these are 100 kΩ potentiometers (104 means 10 followed by 4 zeros = 100000 Ω). The "A" and "B" prefixes are important too. [Read this from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer#Resistance%E2%80%93position_relationship:_%22taper%22) regarding the meaning but, in short: -

- A stands for logarithmic taper
- B stands for linear taper

[image]

> *What means 09HBF25?*

I suspect that may be some manufacturer's prefix part number with the A or B 104 being the full part number.

> *What kind of part is this?*

It's a potentiometer.

Answer (score 0):

It’s the part number of the potentiometer in question.

It’s a potentiometer, an electro-mechanical device which forms a selectable voltage divider.

It’s stamped 104, which most likely mean 100 kohm or bog standard potentiometer. Check its pinout and try to mechanically match it.

But the elephant in the room as that it’s probably just oxide inside your pot. Try with electronic oxide clean spray and rotate the pot back and forth lots of times and see if the situation improves.